# Swift - disable accessibility voiceover?

Tags: swift, accessibility

I was curious if there was a way to disable the voiceover accessibility (or any other type of accessibility feature for that matter - like hear aids, captioning, etc.) in swift?

Essentially, I'm trying to build an application that has a very high likelihood of being used by people with visual impairments and I've tailored my entire application for such people.

But given that this target group may have the voiceover accessibility feature on, can I disable that only within my application?

[image]

I see that on xcode 7, underneath the identity inspector, there is a section for accessibility (picture below) and I tried unchecking that box but it seems like voiceover and the highlighting focus feature are still in effect. Let me know if you have any suggestions or comments, thanks.

Comment: When you say you've tailored the app for people with visual impairments, what sort of tailoring do you mean? Have you tested the app with VoiceOver on, and if so, what effect did it have?

Comment: I mean that I didn't test the Voiceover feature because everything in the app already has a audio file linked to it. I don't want the voiceover feature because it defeats the purpose. I want the end users to simply tap anywhere on the device and play an audio file, with voiceover on, it focuses a cell (or UI element) and reads the label.

Comment: Hmm. I don't believe it's possible to disable a user setting when they open your app. It could lead to various privacy and security problems. Maybe you could include an audio file which asks users to turn off VoiceOver while using your app.

Answer (score 5):

You can set

```
element.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction
```

on any elements that you want to provide custom audio/interactions for.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished in storyboard (See photo).

I came across this thread because I was trying to do this for on a game scene tucked inside of a view container.  To get it to work, I was able to set

`.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction`

on each SKNode that had custom accessibility created for it, and then was able to select the proper options (again see screenshot) on the SKView -> View in Storyboard to allow the game screen to work.

[image: Accessibility Options]